# How to reload an activity with previous state saved?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a game activity and using an sqlite database I populate some buttons, randomly without repetition, and when the game gets finished I popup an alert dialog with OK button an some info. Now, I need when I press OK, to close that popup and in that game activity reload some other data to my buttons, without repetition. This I need to happen twice. I do this in my other game but that popup does not have OK button, it pops up for 3 seconds and using handler closes and my activity reloads with new data without repetition, and that works like a charm. In this game, only OK button is a difference, and it does not work. And I need that OK button. Two problems I have with this.

1. I successfuly reload my activity but with repetition, which tells me that my activity loads from scratch.
2. When the activity loads for the second time, when I press back button I can see previous game activity, which again tells me that I get one activity loaded twice. I only need it once with new data every time.
   Also, my counter does not work, cause after second load, I get 3rd, 4th and so on.

Here are my game and popup activity:

```
public class ToploHladno extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, bIzlaz, bDalje;
    String mButtonText1, mButtonText2, mButtonText3, mButtonText4, mButtonText5, mButtonText6,
    mButtonText7, mButtonText8, mButtonText9, mButtonText10, opis, odgovorNormalized;
    MediaPlayer buttonClicks, buttonFinal, buttonBack;
    public boolean music;
    final Context context = this;
    Editable ukucanRezultat;
    String tacanRezultat, ukucanRezultatVelikaSlova;
    int brojPoena;
    int counter = 0;


    LinkedList<Long> mAnsweredQuestions = new LinkedList<Long>();

    private String generateWhereClause(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Long l : mAnsweredQuestions){
            result.append(" AND _ID <> " + l);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        addListenerOnButton();

        nextQuestion();
    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {


        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        bIzlaz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzlaz);
        bDalje = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDalje);

    }

    public void nextQuestion() {

        counter++;

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{ 

            mDbHelper.open();

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            mButtonText1 = c.getString(2);
            mButtonText2 = c.getString(3);
            mButtonText3 = c.getString(4);
            mButtonText4 = c.getString(5);

            b1.setOnClickListener(this);
            b2.setOnClickListener(this);
            b3.setOnClickListener(this);
            b4.setOnClickListener(this);


            if(counter < 3){

                b1.setText("30 poena");
                b2.setText("25 poena");
                b3.setText("22 poena");
                b4.setText("20 poena");

            }else{
                finish();
            }

        }

            finally{ 
                mDbHelper.close();
            }

    }
```

Popup:

```
public class Popup_opis extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView tvOpis;
    int brojPoenaPrimljeno;
    Button OK;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.popup_opis);

        initVariables();

    }

    private void initVariables() {



        OK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOK);
        tvOpis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOpis);


    OK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Popup_opis.this, ToploHladno.class);
            //intent.putExtra("myMethod", "nextQuestion"); //I tried also this
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are restarting your `ToploHladno  Activity` from your `Popup_opis Activity` using an `Intent`. If the `ToploHladno  Activity` hasn't been finished, which I don't think it has been, then no need for `Intent`. You can call `invalidate()` on the `Views` that you want to be repopulated in `onResume()` after calling `setText()` on them or whatever changes you need to make to those `Views`

```
@Override
public void onResume()   
{
    // change your Buttons however you need in here then say you have btn1
    btn1.invalidate();
}
```

Your first `Activity` isn't being finished so you don't need or probably even want to start it with an `Intent`. You will just return to it after closing your `Dialog Activity` and `onResume()` will be called so you can do what you need in there. This will keep you from redrawing the whole `Layout` by not creating a new instance of your `Activity`.Let me know if this works for what you need or not

[Invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29)

*`startActivityForResult()` example:*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ToploHladno .this, Popup_opis .class);
intent.putExtra("counter", counter);
startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );  //second param is a request code. You will need this later
```

then in pop up activity

```
public class Popup_opis extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

TextView tvOpis;
int brojPoenaPrimljeno;
Button OK;
int counter;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.popup_opis);

        //Get intent
        Intent recIntent = getIntent();
         counter = recIntent.getIntExtra("counter");   //get counter variable from previous activity

OK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
       counter++;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Popup_opis.this, ToploHladno.class);
        intent.putExtra("counter", counter); //SEND BACK COUNTER
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);  // send result
finish();
```

then in your previous activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
// would use REQUEST CODE sent earlier if more than one activity sends back intents here
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        counter = data.getInteExtra("counter", 0);  // get updated counter variable
    }
}
```

[More about startActivityForResult in Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29)

Comment: Well i guess it was not finished, as it's there when i press back button on my phone. How to do that invalidate() thing?

Comment: OK, this is in my game class. But how to call this on OK button if I don't use intent?

Comment: You may be able to use `postInvalidate()` from your other `Activity` but just call `finish()` on your popup `Activity` and remove the `Intent` when they click `ok` and your `onResume()` will be called for your other `Activivty`

Comment: I will try but I think I will get in some problems with my button.setEnable() actions and also with counter. Let me try first. Don't go anywhere. :))

Comment: Just as I thought. After OK click i set my text BUT my first button is disabled. After my second OK click, all my buttons are disabled, only last one is enabled. Also, counter does not work. Also, my mAnsweredQuestions object does not work cause I get the same questions. :((

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you have and exactly what you want. When are your buttons being disabled and why don't you re-enable them in `onResume()`?

Comment: That's not the real issue here. I will enable them one way or another. The real problem is that my counter does not work and even bigger problem is that my questions get repeated.

Comment: I see. You should be able to solve this by making `counter` a `static` variable and add to it when you press "ok"

Comment: And mAnsweredQuestions and repeating questions?

Comment: You can add to counter in `onResume()` also. There you will also need to update your questions. I'm not sure how your DB is setup but you will probably want to use your counter variable to get the next row of questions.

Comment: static counter did not work. I guess nothing is working today.

Comment: Why are you using a separate `Activity` for a simple pop-up anyway? It would be much easier to create an `AlertDialog` in your main `Activity`. Then you have complete access to all member variables with less effort

Comment: Well, I just think it's easier for me to make that popup look like I need it to be. I have one button on it and two textView's. And I also send number of total points to that class. I don't know if I can do all that with alert dialog.

Comment: You can but this should be fine also. Another thing you can do is use `startActivityForResult()` and send counter value then when you close pop-up `Activity` increase counter and send it back.

Comment: I've just saw this startActivityForResult() online, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Can you edit your answer and show me how can I do this with startActivityForResult()?

Comment: And I made counter work. But no luck with repeating question. I just don't get it. How come it works fine when I use handler and now it doesn't?!

Comment: I don't know because I don't know how you are doing it in your `Handler`. I can edit answer for `startActivityForResult()`. Just give me a few

Comment: [Here on this link](https://github.com/Nabukodonosor/spojnice) you can see my game code. In Asocijacije.java. Popup is Popup_asocijacije.java. On the bottom you can see mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,3500);. Popup shows for 3 second and then I reload nextQuestions and there is no repetition. I've accepted your answer just for your effort. :) I don't if I'm allowed to do that, i'm relatively new here.

Comment: Accepting is ok here because we at least took care of your `Button` issues, I think. And thank you for accepting the answer. I have updated with `startActivityForResult()`. Hopefully this can get you started. I will try to take a look at that link soon if I have time. If this gets much biggere we will need a new post with updated code but hopefully this will get you started. I was trying to do it kind of quick so may be syntax errors but I'm sure you will figure that out. I will post relevant link